# How to use two fonts in an anchor tag?

Tags: fonts, hover, anchor

Hi im using two separate fonts in an anchor tag and the hover will work for both fonts if i put my mouse on the second font. However if i put my mouse over the first font, only the first font with change color and the second font will remain the same. I would like both fonts to change color no matter where you put your mouse in the line.

```
<a class="Digestbold" href="#">June Monthly Update - <font class="digestsub">Risk Updates & Life Analysis Statistics (Released July 2020)</font></a>
```

have tried the following:

```
a:hover{COLOR:red;}
&
.Digestbold:hover{COLOR:red;}
.digestsub{COLOR:red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you forgot to add :hover for the second font. It has to become .digestsub:hover{color:red}
Using this code for me it works, you can check the result here:

```css
a:hover{COLOR:red;}
&
.Digestbold:hover{COLOR:red;}
.digestsub:hover{COLOR:red;}
```

```html
<a class="Digestbold" href="#">June Monthly Update - <font class="digestsub">Risk Updates & Life Analysis Statistics (Released July 2020)</font></a>
```

Comment: Sorry that was my typo also had :hover on .digestsub:hover{color:red;}